# White flash between launch image and first view controller

Tags: ios

I have an image with blue/white gradient used as LaunchImage and the same image is presented using the first view controller. I would expect the app will transition from LaunchImage without any graphical distraction, but there appears a short white flash between the Launch Screen and the first VC.

How can I avoid the flash and transition to the first VC without any visual distraction?

Comment: Do you use launch images or the (new in Xcode 6) `LaunchImage.xib` way? I have no such problems with the xib. Doing exactly the same as you want to get.

Comment: I use the traditional static Launch Image, not the new xib method.

Comment: This sounds pretty standard. Care to share some code with us for your initial view controller?

Comment: Good suggestion. I need to review what's happening during the firstVC init, not my code. When I tried new project with the launch image and tested with imageView on firstVC, no flash there. So it is something in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinKoles What caused the flash tho? I have the same problem now.